# Closure of sequence space is the space of all null-sequences

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I`m having a hard time with the following problem.

Show that the closure of $ \phi = \{ x \in l_\infty(\mathbb{N}) : x_j = 0 $ for almost all $ j \in \mathbb{N} \} $ is the space $ c_0 $ of all null sequences.

I don´t exactly understand L-Infinity, since this is very new to me.
But I thought: If a sequence is almost only filled with zeros it must converge to zero as N goes to infinity. But I cant get any further.

PS: $l_\infty$ is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity function. (Space of all functions with supremum < $-\infty$)

I hope someone can kick me back on the right path, or show me how to solve this :D

Comment: In the definition of $\phi$, when you wrote $x_j$, did you mean $x_j=0$?

Comment: Yes, I edited it -> sorry!

Comment: Remember that the closure of a set $X$ is union of $X$ and all limit points of $X$. You just need to find, for each element of $c_0$ some sequence of sequences in $\phi$ that approximates it.

Comment: Sounds plausible, thanks. But what does phi look like ( so i can get a picture in my head ). Is { (0,0,x,...,0,0,),...,(0,0,0,x,x,0,0,0),...} with random sequences of 0  and some integers in them a correct picture? And how can I imagine $c_0$?

Comment: @chopin44 Take any sequence from $\phi$. If for almost all $j$, $x_j = 0$, that means there is only finitely many $j$ so that $x_j \neq 0$, find the greatest $j$ in that set, call it $j_0$. Then for every $k > j_0$, $x_k = 0$. That basically means that after some point, the sequence is all 0s. $\phi$ is essentially a set of all finite sequences (filled with 0s at the end). And $c_0$ is defined as set of all sequences which converge to 0.

Comment: Okay thanks. Is a finite sequence in $\phi$ considered the smallest open set? I cant seem to connect the limit points in an infinite sequence to a finite one. Thinking in terms of an euclidean metric I will always find an open set which does not contain any point of the sequence in $\phi$ -> making no point in $c_0$ a limit point...